# Bandwidth assign and monitoring software for Windows

Tags: windows, network-monitor, network-administration

Recently I have installed TP link router (TP link model WR720N) in my home network. Anybody who knows the password can connect to internet via router.

Is there any software by which I:

- can monitor which devices are connected to my router
- limit/adjust the bandwidth of a connected device
- ban an IP from being connected to my router?

Note: I am using the Windows operating system.

Comment: That software must be run on the router if you want to limit/adjust bandwidth for connected devices. Have you checked whether the router interface allows for it? If not, it might be there's alternative firmware available for the router, such as [OpenWrt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenWrt), which offers "Bandwidth Quotas".

Comment: I have checked , my router doesn't allow it , going to try OpenWrt

Comment: Good choice. If it's available for your router (you didn't specify the model), and that's an acceptable solution (you've asked for something slightly different, which wouldn't be possible) – please let me know, so I can setup a matching answer.

Comment: What Router do you have? (Brand / Model) Would purchasing a different one be an acceptable step in the process?

Comment: TP link  model  WR720N

Comment: So your router [is supported by OpenWRT](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr720n). Have you meanwhile tried that?

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure if these options are not present on your router, but the following will be addressed:

> Part I: can monitor which devices are connected to my router

You should be able to do this via the webpage interface (something like http://192.168.0.1) where you can create an access list. Simply enable this list and then add the mac address of the devices you **want**. Most newer devices will allow you to tick the current connected devices.

If you want to get your hands dirty, you could use something line [nMap](https://nmap.org/). This would be a more manual task to perform however. I will make the *assumption* you do not want to spend money on performing this.

Try [GlassWire Free](https://www.glasswire.com/) for monitoring this. This tool comes with a paid version with more features. I believe this is probably your best solution.

> Part II: limit/adjust the bandwidth of a connected device

You can find a great answer to this right here: [Limit Bandwidth](https://serverfault.com/questions/400992/how-to-limit-bandwidth-speed-from-a-router-for-a-devices-on-a-network). Pay close attention to the comment from @Hopelesssn00b:

> "Alternately, as suggested by Andres, you can install
>   bandwidth-limiting programs on that PC, and depending on the OS and
>   environment you may be able to apply bandwidth limiting settings
>   natively. If it's a specific user causing this disruption, consider
>   using (or creating) acceptable network use policies to deal with it
>   that way."

The better option (in my opinion) would be to enable [QoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service) to ensure the devices you want to get data first do. This is probably the most feasible option as I am unaware of software for iOS and Android to help.

A noteable mention would be to create muliple SSID's on the device to try and help limit who is on one connection, and try to maximise the performance of one SSID through QoS. Not sure of the feasibility of this.

> Part III: ban an ip from being connected to my router

You probably **cannot ban an IP** because chances are you're using DHCP and not a Static IP. Again refer to point 1 where you can create an ACL to prevent devices from adding. You can attack this from two points:

1. Configure this device on the ACL to be blocked by it's MAC Address or;
2. Create a reservation on the modem for an IP and then statically assign this to the device.

Again, I would recommend creating an ACL on your modem. If you need any more help add a comment. If you feel I've answered this, please mark it so.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change this router to anything new?

There are many cheap but semi-professional routers available, that would allow all these needs. As for 2014-2015, the best cost/value option is **MikroTik RB951G‑2HnD**. You can also look at other MikroTik models.

Check also Draytek Vigor and Fritz!Box routers. Or used Cisco models on eBay (however Cisco will be rather expensive, even old/used models).

All of them will meet your needs.